# How to set the distance to label in pyqgis？

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, symbology

```
layer=iface.activeLayer() 
label=QgsPalLayerSettings()
label.readFromLayer(layer) 
label.enabled=True label.fieldName='NAME'
label.placement= QgsPalLayerSettings.OrderedPositionsAroundPoint
label.labelDistance=2 
label.writeToLayer(layer)
```

I want to use label.labelDistance=2 to set it,but it no use.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's `dist`, not `labelDistance`. This should work:

```
layer=iface.activeLayer() 
label=QgsPalLayerSettings()
label.readFromLayer(layer) 
...
label.dist=2 # units are millimeters
label.writeToLayer(layer)
```

Comment: How to set the labe of text size and font family ?